# How to use RegEx in Dart?

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

In a Flutter application, I need to check if a string matches a specific RegEx. However, the RegEx I copied from the JavaScript version of the app *always* returns false in the Flutter app. I verified on [regexr](https://regexr.com/) that the RegEx is valid, and this very RegEx is already being used in the JavaScript application, so it should be correct.

Any help is appreciated!

RegEx : `/^WS{1,2}:\/\/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:56789/i`

Test Code :

```
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
  r"/^WS{1,2}:\/\/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:56789/i",
  caseSensitive: false,
  multiLine: false,
);
print("allMatches : "+regExp.allMatches("WS://127.0.0.1:56789").toString());
print("firstMatch : "+regExp.firstMatch("WS://127.0.0.1:56789").toString());
print("hasMatch : "+regExp.hasMatch("WS://127.0.0.1:56789").toString());
print("stringMatch : "+regExp.stringMatch("WS://127.0.0.1:56789").toString());
```

Output :

```
allMatches : ()
firstMatch : null
hasMatch : false
stringMatch : null
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I think you tried to include options in the raw expression string while you already have it as parameters to RegEx ( /i for case insensitivity is declared as caseSensitive: false).

```
// Removed /i at the end
// Removed / in front - Thanks to Günter for warning
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
  r"^WS{1,2}:\/\/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:56789",
  caseSensitive: false,
  multiLine: false,
);
print("allMatches : "+regExp.allMatches("WS://127.0.0.1:56789").toString());
print("firstMatch : "+regExp.firstMatch("WS://127.0.0.1:56789").toString());
print("hasMatch : "+regExp.hasMatch("WS://127.0.0.1:56789").toString());
print("stringMatch : "+regExp.stringMatch("WS://127.0.0.1:56789").toString());
```

Gives:

```
allMatches : (Instance of '_MatchImplementation')
firstMatch : Instance of '_MatchImplementation'
hasMatch : true
stringMatch : WS://127.0.0.1:56789
```

Comment: The `/` at the beginning also doesn't work in Dart AFAIK

Comment: In DartPad it works for me. Ooops. You are right, I removed that too in DartPad. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! It is a real shame that the [documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) lacks this basic but crucial information. I can only hope that Dart will become as documented as Go one day.

Comment: @NatoBoram, I second on that (and I really wish Go was chosen for Flutter:)

Comment: I can see that the `RegExp` constructor doesn't give a code example, you have to look at the class documentation to see that. We might want to have both, to easily catch users that are used to JavaScript regexp syntax.

Comment: @lrn, I thought I also looked in class documentation and it is not there. If I am mistaken, can you give the link? Dart documentation feels like an automated doc created from class members with no additional explanations and\or examples (there are examples but few, it is more like a try and see yourself).

Comment: The [RegExp class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) has a simple example saying `new RegExp(r"(\w+)")`. It's not a lot of example, but it does show that there are no `/`s in the string. Still, the constructor definitely needs more txt to say what fx `caseInsensitive` means.

Comment: @lrn, I see, that was all I saw too. Anyway, I love Flutter thus have to love Dart too (wishing it used Go instead aside).

Comment: Could drop the toString()
```+regExp.stringMatch("WS://127.0.0.1:56789").toString()```

Answer (score 176):

This is a more general answer for future viewers.

Regex in Dart works much like other languages. You use the [`RegExp`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) class to define a matching pattern. Then use `hasMatch()` to test the pattern on a string.

### Examples

Alphanumeric

```
final alphanumeric = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$');
alphanumeric.hasMatch('abc123');  // true
alphanumeric.hasMatch('abc123%'); // false
```

Hex colors

```
RegExp hexColor = RegExp(r'^#?([0-9a-fA-F]{3}|[0-9a-fA-F]{6})$');
hexColor.hasMatch('#3b5');     // true
hexColor.hasMatch('#FF7723');  // true
hexColor.hasMatch('#000000z'); // false
```

Extracting text

```
final myString = '25F8..25FF    ; Common # Sm   [8] UPPER LEFT TRIANGLE';

// find a variable length hex value at the beginning of the line
final regexp = RegExp(r'^[0-9a-fA-F]+'); 

// find the first match though you could also do `allMatches`
final match = regexp.firstMatch(myString);

// group(0) is the full matched text
// if your regex had groups (using parentheses) then you could get the 
// text from them by using group(1), group(2), etc.
final matchedText = match?.group(0);  // 25F8
```

There are some more examples [here](https://github.com/suragch/string_validator/blob/master/lib/src/validator.dart).

### See also:

- [Extracting text from a string with regex groups in Dart](https://medium.com/flutter-community/extracting-text-from-a-string-with-regex-groups-in-dart-b6be604c8a69?sk=a0c94b1a6fba950dfef380d67f5b858e)

Comment: @LeoK, It does work but it isn't very useful in this case. What you get is a list with two items: everything before `25F8` at the start of the string (which is an empty string) and everything after it.

Comment: The medium article in "see also" section is hidden behind a paywall https://medium.com/flutter-community/extracting-text-from-a-string-with-regex-groups-in-dart-b6be604c8a69

Comment: @Kevo1ution, Thanks for telling me. I've updated the link with a non-paywalled version.