# How do I use regexp in flutter?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

[image] I want the format shown in the photo.
I used this code

```
RegExp(r'^(?=.*[0-9])(?=\\S+$).{8,40}$').hasMatch(text).
```

This code is ok for Java but not for Dart. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that double-backslashing might be unnecessary, and:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=\S+$).{8,40}$
```

might simply work.

---

Maybe, you might want to a bit strengthen/secure the pass criteria, maybe with some expression similar to:

```
(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[~!?@#$%^&*_-])[A-Za-z0-9~!?@#$%^&*_-]{8,40}$
```

which allows,

- a minimum of one digit,
- a minimum of one upper/lower case, and
- at least one of these chars: `~!?@#$%^&*_-`

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gdEJTy/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/gdEJTy/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### Reference

- [Dart >> dart:core >> RegExp abstract class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html)
- [Regex for password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a)
- [How to use RegEx in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757486/how-to-use-regex-in-dart)

Comment: Thanks Emma.This is work.Where i look regexp documentation in dart.I don't understand how work.Thanks again

Comment: The reason this works, and the original does not, is that you are using a *raw* string in Dart (the "r" prefix), and you weren't in Java. In a raw string, interpolations and *escapes* are disabled so your `\\S` is read literally by the RegExp parser as an escaped backslash and a capital "S". If you write only `\S`, the RegExp parser will see it as the non-whitespace escape code instead. You need the two backslashes in Java (or in non-raw Dart strings) because the *string* parser converts `\\S` to `\S`, and then the RegExp parser sees `\S` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is your entire solution function for checking valid constraint of the password as well as using regex expression in Dart.

```
String? validatePassword(String? value) {
        String missings = "";
        if (value!.length < 8) {
          missings += "Password has at least 8 characters\n";
        }

        if (!RegExp("(?=.*[a-z])").hasMatch(value)) {
          missings += "Password must contain at least one lowercase letter\n";
        }
        if (!RegExp("(?=.*[A-Z])").hasMatch(value)) {
          missings += "Password must contain at least one uppercase letter\n";
        }
        if (!RegExp((r'\d')).hasMatch(value)) {
          missings += "Password must contain at least one digit\n";
        }
        if (!RegExp((r'\W')).hasMatch(value)) {
          missings += "Password must contain at least one symbol\n";
        }

        //if there is password input errors return error string
        if (missings != "") {
          return missings;
        }

        //success
        return null;
 }
```

[image: there's my result image]