# how to validate a textfield for 0-9 digits and for one character in flutter?

Tags: validation, flutter, dart, textfield

I want to validate a text field for a Identity Card number. ID no has 9 digits and one character. Here is my code. 
how to do this validation?
"code"

```
Widget buildIDno(){
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'National Identy Card Number'),
      validator: (String value){
        if(value.isEmpty){
          return 'ID no is Required';
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: You can use a regular expression to validate the data. But writing a regular expression depends on your card number format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do that with regular expressions, take a look [here (usage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757486/how-to-use-regex-in-dart)
and [here for the official reference](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html).

But a regex pattern in your case could look like that: `[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]{1}` which means that we want to match the group `[0-9]`(= any number between 0 and 9) exactly 9 times and the `[a-zA-Z]` (= lower- and uppercase letters from A to Z) group just one time.

Also, please use the search engine first before asking a question, as some effort of your own should go into that, we are not here to write your code.