# How to put all regex matches into a string list

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have a list of random dates formatted like:

```
String x ="Text(\"key:[2020-08-23 22:22, 2020-08-22 10:11, 2020-02-22 12:14]\"),"
```

I can use the `\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}` regex to match all dates in `x`:

```
RegExp regExp79 = new RegExp(
    r'\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}',
);
var match79 = regExp79.allMatches("$x");
var mylistdate = match79;
```

So, the matches are:

```
match 1 = 2020-08-22 22:22
match 2 = 2020-08-22 10:11
match 3 = 2020-02-22 12:14
```

I want to convert the `Iterable<RegExpMatch>` into a list of strings, so that the output of my list looks like:

```
[2020-08-22 22:22, 2020-08-22 10:11, 2020-02-22 12:14]
```

Comment: The question is more a question of possibilities of match an impreditive and random list that a X regex, I use regex I can find how to match my list but I don't know ( in the context of a listString) if it's possible and if YES how to add multiple  match groupe in a ListString

Comment: Please consider adding the code you tried to solve the problem in order to help you.

Comment: it's clear stringList.add("$groupe1+groupe2+groupe3"); // try to groupe all match in a list, but don't know to to write correctly if number of group are variable

prefs.setStringList("my_Key",stringList_value); // save my list with a key

Comment: I post this code but with abstract representation because I havn't the solution, I need help to found this

Comment: here is the regex \d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}

Comment: I can match each date from my list but don't know how to add each match in my list

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757486/how-to-use-regex-in-dart), you just need to use [`regExp.allMatches()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/RegExp/allMatches.html)

Comment: I edit my post , with complet code and use of allMatches but I have this issue :" the argument type 'Iterable<RegExpMatch>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>'

Comment: How do you declare `prefs`? I guess you forgot to escape `"` inside an `x` string literal, too.

Comment: don't know if I understand but I think I declare like that      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

Comment: Yes I have  " in x String because I use    allkeys=prefs.getKeys().map<Widget>((key) {
        return Text(key+ ":" + prefs.get(key).toString());
      }).toList();

Comment: Please post the [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Add all code necessary to repro the problem. Or remove redundant code. Do you just want to convert `mylistdate` to a string list?

Comment: My goal is to load all key value in a string, that the user can save in email. And if he change device he can past this list to restaure au key value of previous device, I have found on stack overflow a code to do this but don't found how to remove Text("...") around each key data, so I use regex to filtre this if it a problem

Comment: Is `var mylistdate = match79.map((z) => z.group(0));` all you need?

Comment: Yes I have all date match in mylistdate, but want ADD match in a Stringlist. If I have 5 date match I want to save these match in index[0] index[1] index[2] index[3] index[4] of my String list

Comment: Thank you I will try, it's look what I need

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`allMatches` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/RegExp/allMatches.html) returns an `Iterable<RegExpMatch>` value. It contains all the [`RegExpMatch`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/RegExpMatch-class.html) objects that contain some details about the matches. You need to invoke the `.group(0)` method on each `RegExpMatch` object to get the string value of the match.

So, you need to `.map` the results:

```
your_regex.allMatches(x).map((z) => z.group(0)).toList()
```

Code:

```
String x ="Text(\"key:[2020-08-23 22:22, 2020-08-22 10:11, 2020-02-22 12:14]\"),";
RegExp regExp79 = new RegExp(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}');
var mylistdate = regExp79.allMatches(x).map((z) => z.group(0)).toList();
print(mylistdate);
```

Output:

```
[2020-08-23 22:22, 2020-08-22 10:11, 2020-02-22 12:14]
```