# How to extract data from webserver to flutter app

Tags: database, flutter, web

how can I add an auto-update my code in a flutter? I am creating an app to check the market rate or wholesale rate of chicken, mutton, and seafood (all Alive) so I don't want to waste my time on copy-pasting the price every day. I want something that extracts data from a website and inserts it to my flutter app. that changes the price in all as thee prie on website changes. I also want to upload it to the play store.

Comment: Read these articles: [http](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/httpserver), [regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757486/how-to-use-regex-in-dart), [regexp](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/RegExp-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use an API to extract the data from whatever website you like and you can either set a timer which at regular intervals checks if the price has changed and updates if necessary or using an API will reload prices when the app is closed and opened again anyway.