# Regex match doesn't seem to work in dart, but works in javascript

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make utility function to parse a string and return a list of regex matches. The string that returns from my server looks something like this:

```
        {{Yoga dance class}}
        {{Herzog, Walter and Glover}}
        {{Yoga, dance}}
        {{Intermediate}}
```

I'm trying to match the regex like this:

```dart
class ParsedClassDescription {
  final String userFacingDescription;
  final String? organization;
  final String? categories;
  final String? level;

  const ParsedClassDescription({
    required this.userFacingDescription,
    this.organization,
    this.categories,
    this.level,
  });
}

ParsedClassDescription? parseClassDescription(String? description) {
  if (description == null) {
    return null;
  }

  final regex = RegExp(r'/(?<={{\s*).*?(?=\s*}})/gs');
  
  final match = regex.allMatches(description);

  return const ParsedClassDescription(userFacingDescription: 'test test ignore this');
}
```

I'm not exactly sure if this RegExp works... am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this comment by Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757486/how-to-use-regex-in-dart?rq=1#comment86531320_49758035) says, remove the '/' from the beginning of the string. The [answer that is a comment on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758035/15170120) points out that you don't need the '/g' (`.allMatches()` performs that function). I ran your regex in DartPad and got it to return matches by removing both of those characters and the 's':

```dart
final regex = RegExp(r'(?<={{\s*).*?(?=\s*}})');
final match = regex.allMatches("{{Yoga dance class}} {{Herzog, Walter and Glover}} {{Yoga, dance}} {{Intermediate}}");
```

Comment: Wow that's seriously specific! Thank you for pointing out that answer. I may have misread your comment and though you only removed the `/` and the `s`, leaving `g`, but it turns out i had to completely remove that too. The end result looks like this: `RegExp(r'(?<={{\s*).*?(?=\s*}})')`

Comment: Sorry, yes, I removed '/gs' - that wasn't clear lol.